# Force pdf download not working when include blog-header.php

Tags: customization, wp-blog-header.php

I have this code which works in a file called downloads/download.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
readfile('file.pdf');
?>
```

It correctly prompts to download file.pdf.

I need to track downloads so I want to make use of various WP functions.
To bring the page inside WP I added blog-header.php like so:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-blog-header.php');
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
readfile('file.pdf');
?>
```

This returns a 404. Does anyone know why bringing the page inside WP would cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Wordpress is having problem with the url of your external script and throws a 404 error from the `handle_404()` function in the `wp` class in `/wp-includes/class-wp.php`

You can try to overcome that using for example `status_header(200)`

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-blog-header.php');
status_header(200);
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
readfile('file.pdf');
?>
```

### ps:

It is informative to look at the source for the Wordpress query setup  `wp()` that is called from the file `wp-blog-header.php`.

This function is defined in `/wp-includes/functions.php` and looks like this

```
function wp( $query_vars = '' ) {
    ...cut...
    $wp->main( $query_vars );
    ...cut...
}
```

where

```
 function main($query_args = '') {
    ...cut...
      $this->handle_404();
    ...cut...
}
```

and

```
 function handle_404() {
    ...cut...
    // Guess it's time to 404.
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    nocache_headers();
    ...cut...
}
```

is from the `wp` class in `/wp-includes/class-wp.php`.